# Vue contenteditable cursor jumps to the beginning on change in Safari

Tags: vue.js, safari

NOTE: This question has been asked, but the solutions don't seem to work in my case, it must be a different issue. I wonder if syncing with Firestore plays a role here.

I have this method that gets called when a contenteditable is changed:

```
async function updateItem(data: { [key: string]: any }) {
  // Save current cursor position
  const savedCursorPosition = window.getSelection()!.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange()
  console.log(savedCursorPosition)

  hideAllPoppers()

  let hasEmptyItem = false
  Object.values(data).forEach((value) => {
    if (value === '') {
      hasEmptyItem = true
    }
  })
  if (hasEmptyItem) {
    message.value = 'Value cannot be blank'
    hasError.value = true
    return
  }

  hasError.value = false
  message.value = 'Saving...'
  const updateResponse: DbEditResponse = await websiteDataClient.updateContentGroupItem(
    websiteDataStore.contentGroups[props.groupIndex],
    data,
    itemData.value!.id
  )
  message.value = updateResponse.message
  if (updateResponse.status === DbEditStatus.error) {
    hasError.value = true
  }
  nextTick(() => {
    window.getSelection()!.removeAllRanges()
    window.getSelection()!.addRange(savedCursorPosition)
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    message.value = ''
  }, 5000)
}
```

Here is one of the many places it gets called:

```html
    <h1
      :contenteditable="!isLoading"
      v-if="itemData!.description"
      @input="updateItem({ description: ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).innerText })"
    >
      {{ itemData!.description }}
    </h1>
```

However, only in Safari, a single character change causes the cursor to move back to the front of the text. The pinia store updates when the firestore data is changed, therefore I speculate that plays a role somewhere, but I'm not entirely sure if that is true or what exactly that role is.

Comment: What is your `hideAllPoppers` method ?

Comment: It seems like you are modifying some position of the cursor and it will maybe impact your UX ...

Comment: @Sayf-Eddine poppers are drop-downs